# Combo Box input to Select MySQL data of current day

Tags: php, mysql, select, combobox

Thanks for any help.
I have a date combo box which chooses from today and next 6 days.
The output is currently set to show only CURRENTDATE data from MySQL
My goal is to show data not from CURRENT DATE but from date selected fro ComboBox.

Thanks again.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Connecting MySQL Server</title>

<style>
table,td,th
{
border:1px solid orange;
}
table
{
width:100%;
}
th
{
height:50px;
}
</style>


</head>
<body>
<select name="select" id="select">
<?php
$date = time();
$num_days = 7;
for($i=0; $i<=$num_days; ++$i)
{
$date = mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m") , date("d")+$i, date("Y"));
$date = date('D j M', $date);
echo " <option value='{$date}'>{$date}</option>\n";
}
?>
</select>



<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","XXXXXXX","XXXXXXX","XXXXXXX");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}


$result = mysqli_query($con,"
SELECT *
FROM movies2 
WHERE date = CURDATE()



");



echo "<table border='2'>
<tr>
<th>Movie</th>
<th>Rating</th>
<th>Time</th>
<th>Date</th>
<th>Code</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td nowrap>" . $row['movie'] . "</td>";
echo "<td nowrap>" . $row['rating'] . "</td>";
echo "<td nowrap>" . $row['time'] . "</td>";
echo "<td nowrap>" . $row['date'] . "</td>";
echo "<td nowrap>" . $row['code'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: do you know how to program in PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in general lines, you need to put the  element within a form, whose action is the same page and then in the query you need to replace CURDATE() with a variable.

This variable is the value of "select", if available, or CURDATE().

However you need to sanitize the form variable to avoid sql injection.

Better, use a prepared statement instead of a simple string. So, your variable will feed the parameter of the prepared statement.